# Options for storing huge tile map

Tags: java, database, game-engine, procedural-generation, bigdata

I am creating a pseudo-turn-based online strategy browser game where many people play in the same world over a long period(months). For this, I want to have a map of 64000x64000 tiles = 4 billion tiles. I need about 6-10 bytes of data per tile, making up a total of around 30GB of data for storing the map.

Each tile should have properties such as type(water, grass, desert, mountain), resource(wood, cows, gold) and playerBuilt(road, building)

The client will only ever need access to about 100x100 tiles at the same time.

I have handled the map on client side under control. The problem that I'm faced with is how to store, retrieve and modify information from this map on the server side.

Required functionality:

1. Create, store, and modify 64000x64000 tilemap.
2. Show 100x100 part of the map to the client.
3. Make modifications on the map such as roads, buildings, and depleted resources.

What I have considered so far:

1. Procedural generation: Procedurally generating whichever part of the map is needed on the fly. Making sure that given the same seed, it always generates the same map. The main problem I have with this is that there will be modifications to the map during the game. Note: Less than 1% of the tiles would be modified during the game and it could be possible to store modifications with coordinates in an outside array. Loading them on top of the procedural generation.
2. Databases: Generating the map at the start of the game and storing it in a database. A friend advised me against this for such a huge tile map and told me that I'd probably want to store it in memory instead.
3. Keeping it all in memory on the server side: Keeping it in memory in a data structure. Seems like a nice way to do it if the map was smaller but for 4 billion tiles that would be a lot to keep in memory.

I was planning on using java+mysql for back-end for this project. I'm still in early phases and open to change technology if needed.

My question is: Which of the three approaches above seem viable and/or are there other ways to do it which I have not considered?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's possible that you'll get some useful answers to this question but, in general, it's really too broad for this site. The correct answer is going to be 'it depends' on dozens of factors about how your game will be designed. If you could be more specific about the issues you see in each solution and ask about how they could be resolved then you might get better info. Don't be surprised if this is closed on you as too broad.

Comment: Approximately how much data do you have per tile? A solution for 8 bits per tile will be very different than 1 mb per tile...

Comment: Sprinter - Thanks for the welcome, I'll try to keep it more concise in the future.
Pikalek - Approximately 16 bytes of data per tile.

Comment: What are these 16 bytes of data exactly? It could be perfectly possible to make the tiles consume less memory by storing references to common value combinations only. E.g. cows don't live in water so type and resource could possibly be combined in a useful way.

Comment: Interesting idea, Markus Benko. Thanks.
What I was thinking was:
I need a few bits(2 bytes?) to determine type(grass) and resource types(cow, gold).
Then I need a couple of larger integers(4 bytes each) to determine amount of resources remaining and an ID reference to a potential playerBuiltObject.
This makes up an upper bound of around 10 bytes unless I need to store any additional information. With average being around 6 bytes since less than 1% of tiles will have playerBuiltObjects.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on:

- how much RAM you got (or player/users got)
- Is most of the tile map empty (sparse) ? Opposite is dense.
- Is there a default terrain (like empty or water ?)

If sparse, use a hashmap instead of a 2D array.

If dense it will be much more challenging and you may need to use a database or some special data structures + cache.
You may detect hot zones and keep them in memory for a while, dead zones (no players there, no activity ...) can be stored in the database and read on demand.
You may also load data in several passes: first just the terrain, then other objects... each layer could be stored in a different way. For example the terrain could be perlin noise generated + another layer which can be modified.